# Referencing flattened busses in module instantiation

Tags: verilog

I have a Verilog gate-level netlist generated by the Synopsys Design Compiler.

DC was directed to flatten all busses and ports when creating the netlist, and the module declaration is given below:

```
module DES_SBOX1 ( CLK, \ptext[5] , \ptext[4] , \ptext[3] , \ptext[2] , 
    \ptext[1] , \ptext[0] , \key[5] , \key[4] , \key[3] , \key[2] , 
    \key[1] , \key[0] , \ctext[3] , \ctext[2] , \ctext[1] , 
    \ctext[0]  );
```

My problem is that when I try to use this module in a testbench, I receive syntax errors because I am not sure how to reference the port names (because of the backslash).

Here is an attempt at instantiating one of these modules:

```
DES_SBOX1 feistel( .CLK(CLK_tb),
                 .ptext[5](ptext_tb[5]),
                 .ptext[4](ptext_tb[4]),
                 .ptext[3](ptext_tb[3]),
                 .ptext[2](ptext_tb[2]),
                 .ptext[1](ptext_tb[1]),
                 .ptext[0](ptext_tb[0]),
                 .key[5](1'b0),
                 .key[4](1'b0),
                 .key[3](1'b0),
                 .key[2](1'b0),
                 .key[1](1'b0),
                 .key[0](1'b0),
                 .ctext[5](ctext_tb[5]),
                 .ctext[4](ctext_tb[4]),
                 .ctext[3](ctext_tb[3]),
                 .ctext[2](ctext_tb[2]),
                 .ctext[1](ctext_tb[1]),
                 .ctext[0](ctext_tb[0]),
                );
```

And here is the error message from Modelsim PE:

```
    ** Error: C:\Users\Kristin\Desktop\des_feistel_90nm\testbench.v(14): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'ptext'.

    ** Error: C:\Users\Kristin\Desktop\des_feistel_90nm\testbench.v(14): near "[": syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')'
```

I've also tried using the backslash in the instantiation itself, like so:

```
 .\ptext[5](ptext_tb[5])
```

This also gives a syntax error.

I'm wondering what the significance of the backslash is in the first place?

Any ideas on how to correctly instantiate this module are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are running into Verilog's *escaped identifiers* gotcha.  From the IEEE standard reference:

> §2.7.1 Escaped identifiers
>
> Escaped identifiers shall start with the backslash character () and
> end with white space (space, tab, newline). They provide a means of
> including any of the printable ASCII characters in an identifier (the
> decimal values 33 through 126, or 21 through 7E in hexadecimal).
>
> Neither the leading backslash character nor the terminating white
> space is considered to be part of the identifier. Therefore, an
> escaped identifier \cpu3 is treated the same as a nonescaped
> identifier cpu3.

Not only do you need to properly write down escaped port name, but you also need to make sure you don't forget to put a whitespace at the end. For example:

```
DES_SBOX1 feistel( .CLK(CLK_tb),
                 .\ptext[5] (ptext_tb[5]),
                 .\ptext[4] (ptext_tb[4]),
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow, I've never seen a netlist with port names escaped like that. I supposed it's because they have `[]` as part of the port name.

Try dropping the port names from the port connection list.  That is, use the positional mapping instead of connecting by name.  Normally this would be discouraged because "by name" is more readable, but it may get you past the compile error in this case.

e.g.

```
DES_SBOX1 feistel(CLK_tb,        // CLK
                 ptext_tb[5],    // ptext[5]
                 ptext_tb[4],    // ptext[4]
                 ptext_tb[3],    // ptext[3]
                 ptext_tb[2],    // ptext[2]
                 ptext_tb[1],    // ptext[1]
                 ptext_tb[0],    // ptext[0]
                 1'b0,           // key[5]
                 1'b0,           // key[4]
                 1'b0,           // key[3]
                 1'b0,           // key[2]
                 1'b0,           // key[1]
                 1'b0,           // key[0]
                 ctext_tb[5],    // ctext[5]
                 ctext_tb[4],    // ctext[4]
                 ctext_tb[3],    // ctext[3]
                 ctext_tb[2],    // ctext[2]
                 ctext_tb[1],    // ctext[1]
                 ctext_tb[0]     // ctext[0]
                );
```